# Deleting vector layer from GeoPackage using PyQGIS

Tags: python, vector, pyqgis-3, geopackage, delete

Programmatically I have added the vector layers to an existing GeoPackage in QGIS 3.2 using Python. Similarly, I would like to delete a layer from the existing GeoPackage using Python code. But there is no example/help found online.

Here is my code to add the selected layers to an existing Geo package:

```py
layer = self.iface.activeLayer() 
layer.startEditing()
gpkgPath='D:/AA/Layer/sample_gpkg'
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.actionOnExistingFile =QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer   
options.layerName = 'test'
_writer=QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,gpkgPath,options)
```

[image]

Comment: There is quite a lot to do when a table is totally and properly dropped from GeoPackage (drop spatial index, drop a bunch of triggers, remove outdated rows from metadata tables, and finally drop the table itself). If QGIS does not have a dedicated method for that (I don't know if it does) the easiest alternative is probably to let GDAL to drop the table with SQL `DROP TABLE layer_name` as documented in https://www.gdal.org/drv_geopackage.html.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [SpatiaLite execute SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html#qgisspatialiteexecutesql) tool and `drop table`:

```
gpkg = '/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/overlaps.gpkg'
layer = 'overlaps'

processing.run("native:spatialiteexecutesql", {'DATABASE':'{0}|layername={1}'.format(gpkg, lyr),
    'SQL':'drop table {0}'.format(layer)})
```

[image]