# Write two layers to geopackage

Tags: pyqgis, geopackage

I am trying to write two layers into geopackage without success.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *

def drawLay ( namee, x1, y1 ) :
    lay = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=epsg:2039', namee , 'memory')
    pr = lay.dataProvider()
    lay.startEditing()
    fet = QgsFeature()
    fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(x1,y1)) )
    pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
    lay.commitChanges()
    lay.updateExtents()
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lay)

# create two layers    
drawLay ( 'aa', 150000, 400000)
drawLay ( 'bb', 150100, 400000)

#write this layers into geoPackage 
GpName = r'c:\temp\gpk_file.gpkg'
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer 
options.EditionCapability = QgsVectorFileWriter.CanAddNewLayer  
for layer in  iface.mapCanvas().layers() :  
    namee =layer.name()
    print (namee)
    options.layerName = namee  
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, GpName, options )
```

Comment: what doesn't work? what does happen?

Comment: Your code work perfectly, print `_writer` for show a error, maybe you don't have administrator permission for write on C

Comment: Tested the code on QGIS3 on LINUX @FranRaga it showed a (2, 'Opening of data source in update mode failed (OGR error: )')

Comment: On linux but your path is a windows format!you need admin permisions I think for write a geopackage

Comment: Thanks to all. @IanTurton- I am trying to write more than one layer to geopackage allready a week without success.

Comment: @FranRaga & Riccardo- I have adminstrator permisions , but on print (_writer) get  (2, 'Opening of data source in update mode failed (OGR error: )') message.  I work with Win 10 (and 7) , QGis 3.6.2

Comment: I found it! Thanks to hint in this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320738/deleting-vector-layer-from-geopackage-using-pyqgis?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to check that the file doesn't exist.
Depending on whether it is a new file or an update, you must change the value of `actionOnExistingFile`

Another change you must make is `iface.mapCanvas(). Layers()`, and use `QgsProject.instance ().MapLayers ().Values()`

Add code :

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *

def drawLay ( namee, x1, y1 ) :
    lay = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=epsg:2039', namee , 'memory')
    pr = lay.dataProvider()
    lay.startEditing()
    fet = QgsFeature()
    fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(x1,y1)) )
    pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
    lay.commitChanges()
    lay.updateExtents()
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lay)

# create two layers    
drawLay ( 'aa', 150000, 400000)
drawLay ( 'bb', 150100, 400000)

#write this layers into geoPackage 
GpName = r'D:\temp\gpk_file.gpkg'
for layer in  QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() :  
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions() 
    options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer #Update mode
    options.EditionCapability = QgsVectorFileWriter.CanAddNewLayer 
    options.layerName = layer.name()  
    print("Update mode")
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, GpName, options)
    if _writer:
            print(layer.name(), _writer)
    if _writer[0] == QgsVectorFileWriter.ErrCreateDataSource :
        print("Create mode")
        options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteFile #Create mode
        _writer= QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, GpName, options)
        if _writer:
                print(layer.name(), _writer)
```

**tested on QGIS 3.6.2 and win 10**

Comment: thanks, I saw your answer after I had write my "discovery".

Answer (score 2):

I found it! Thanks to hint in this post [Deleting vector layer from Geopackage using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320738/deleting-vector-layer-from-geopackage-using-pyqgis?rq=1)
I found that there is difference for entering first layer to geopackage and for adding next layers. Here is my code:

```
GpName = r'c:\temp\gpk_file.gpkg'
firstt = True
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions() 
for layer in  QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() :  
    if firstt :            
        firstt = False
    else :
        options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer 
        options.EditionCapability = QgsVectorFileWriter.CanAddNewLayer  
    options.layerName = layer.name()
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, GpName, options )
```

Comment: this resolvs "Opening of data source in update mode failed (OGR error: )"